# How to make ListView Items align at bottom of a container with a fixed height without using reverse in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter project, I have a **container** with a fixed height. Inside that container I have a **Listview**.

**Here's the code-**

```
return new Scaffold(

  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("All Values"),
  ),

  body: new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[

      Container(
        height: isLoading ? 50.0 : 0,
        color: Colors.white70,
        child: Center(
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),

      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          height: 350,
          color: Colors.red,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,

          child:
          new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length-8,

            itemBuilder: (BuildContext cxtx, int index) {
              return Padding(
                padding:  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0.0, 10, 0),
                child: Container(
                  child: showCard(index, radius),
                ),
              );

            },

            controller: _scrollController,
          ),

        ),),

    ],
  ),

  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,

);
```

The code outputs like below-

[image]

So, the problem is I want to align these items at bottom left of the container. I could have done that using **reverse: true** but I need the list items with the same sequence. So, I need suggestion how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need those items in a row or a column? Follow with a row possibility:
Try this:

```
 return new Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("All Values"),
  ),
  body:  Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      if(isLoading)
        Container(
        height: 50.0 ,
        color: Colors.white70,
        child: Center(
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          height: 350,
          color: Colors.red,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length - 8,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext cxtx, int index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0.0, 10, 0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Text('asdf'),
                ),
              );
            },
            controller: _scrollController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
);
```

Comment: I want them in Column, vertically bottom left of the Container.

Comment: Ok, I made on modification, please run, and paste the print here, to check if still needing adjustment

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Now, it shows none of the items using your code.

Comment: OK, try again, actually the list its alreadying generating a column, probably

Comment: Didn't work as well, now it is showing top of the container.

Comment: Post the print screen here if possible

Comment: Ok, try again, and paste again.. You should use Flutter Inspect to identify the heights, margins, ..., of each element of your view. This tool is inside your Android Studio

Comment: Ok, again please

Comment: Now, it is showing all white screen. Please check the modified code in my question. Here I have shared the whole scaffold that should help you more to understand the problem.

Comment: Last time, and I give up. I am without a compiler with me, its complicated without the Flutter Inspect. You should try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
StoreConnector<_ViewModel, List<Message>>(
      converter: (store) {
        // check mark ,reverse data list
        if (isReverse) return store.state.dialogList;
        return store.state.dialogList.reversed.toList();
      },
      builder: (context, dialogs) {
        // Add a callback when UI render after. then change it direction;
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((t) {
          // check it's items could be scroll
          bool newMark = _listViewController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0;
          if (isReverse != newMark) { // need 
            isReverse = newMark;  // rebuild listview
            setState(() {});
          }
        });

        return ListView.builder(
          reverse: isReverse, // 反转列表，insert数据时，刷新到0，加载更多时，滚动偏移不变
          controller: _listViewController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => _bubbleItem(context, dialogs[index], index),
          itemCount: dialogs.length,
        );
      },
    )
```